# Array of Strings only saving the most recent input

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, nodes, hashtable

I am currently working on a hashtable program, but that isn't the  problem, I have a insert function, but when I run it, the insert function only saves the most recent string read from the text.txt file, if the line is like "Finn 34" it has to insert Finn into the hash table with the value 34, if the hashed index already has something in it, it just reports a collision, however if it is the same String such as "Finn 98" it should report that Finn is already in that index. The problem is that every string points to the original name from the fscanf, I'm almost certain that the way to fix it is with malloc, but every-time I try to use it, it won't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TableSize 45
#define Max 50
///// dont forget the edit in main

typedef struct node {
    char name[Max];
    int value;
} node;
node array[Max];


void init_array(){

    for (int i = 0; i < TableSize; i++){
      //array[i] = NULL;
    }
} 


void insert(int index, node *p){

  /*char * tempName = malloc (sizeof (char) * 50);
  strcpy(tempName, p->name);*/

  if (array[index].value != 0){
    //if (array[index]->name == p->name){
    if (strcmp(array[index].name, p->name) == 0){
      printf("Error %s already exists at index %d\n\n", array[index].name, index);
    }
    else{
      printf("Collision occured at index %d with\n\n", index);
    }
  }
  else{
    array[index] = *p;
    strcpy(array[index].name, p->name);
    printf("Stored %s with value of %d at index %d.\n\n", array[index].name, array[index].value, index);
  }

} 

int hash(char name[Max]){
  int key = 0;
  for (int i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; ++i){
    char x = name[i];
    key = key + x;
  }
  key = key % TableSize;
  return key;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  init_array();
  FILE *fp;
  char ch;
  char name[Max];
  int x, HaValue;


  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (NULL == fp) {
        //printf("file can't be opened \n");
        fp = fopen("text.txt", "r"); ///////get rid of when done
    }
  node * p;  
  p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 do{
  x = 0;

  int counter = 0;
  if (fscanf(fp, "%49s", name) != 1) break;
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &x) != 1) counter = 1;
  HaValue = hash(name);
  p->value = x;
  strcpy(p->name, name);
  if (counter != 0) {
  }
  else{
    insert(HaValue, p);
  }
  
  } while(!feof(fp));

  printf("%d %s %d", 12, array[12].name, array[12].value);
  //test to see if the name was correctly saved. should be "12 Dog 12"

  
    // Closing the file
    fclose(fp);
  
  return 0;
}
```

This is the text.txt document

```
Brom 89
Paul 25
Jake 34
Yokai 45
Jake
Dog 20
Paul 30
Brom
Kron 40
Finn 234
```

Comment: `node p = {.value = x};` That is an auto variable whose lifetime is one iteration of the loop. That is, the `p` variable no longer exists as soon as each loop iteration completes. Storing a pointer to it and using it after that is Undefined Behaviour. "*I'm almost certain that the way to fix it is with malloc, but every-time I try to use it, it won't work*". Using `malloc` is the right way so please show your attempt and describe what specific problem you have with it.

Comment: "char * tempName = malloc (sizeof (char) * 50);"  in the insert function was my attempt, are you saying I should make the malloc in main with node p?

Comment: "*are you saying I should make the malloc in main with node p"*. Yes.

Comment: `if (array[index]->name == p->name)` You can't compare strings like this, you need to use `strcmp`. `tempName` seems to serve no purpose other than creating a memory leak. `if (fscanf(fp, "%s", name) == 3)` will never be true. `fscanf` returns the number of successful conversions or EOF so it will only return 1 or EOF for that format string.

Comment: @kaylum, I'm not very good with malloc, like at all, I don't really understand how to implement it, I tried `node p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` but its not compiling, do I need to create a separate array of nodes? if so, would it be better to do that with the original array node?
@RetiredNinja I'll change to strcmp and get rid of tempName, I wanted to show my failed attempt at malloc, and the `if (fscanf(fp, "%s", name) == 3)` is only there because even with EOF, it would throw warnings but would run completely fine unless I did the if statement

Comment: `node *p;  p = malloc(sizeof(struct node))` That is, `p` needs to be a pointer.

Comment: I updated the code in the original post to show how I implemented it, but its printing all garbled text for the string and int values.

Comment: @kaylum hashtables don't have to be allocated using dynamic memory; the collection is defined separate from storage duration. In this case we can see OP would like a fixed size array of fixed size nodes, for a total of say 2.5KB... That's totally doable with static storage duration.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as tempName is undeclared.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the same Max for both key size and array size.  Also, by convention, constants are upper case.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%s", name) == 3` is nonsense. It will either return number of fields read (0, 1) or EOF.  It will never return 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see an array declared with static storage duration (`array`), as a fixed number of node pointers. You later declare the node to be pointed to with automatic storage duration, which is where your error occurs, as the nodes get effectively destroyed and then trampled "on the stack" when the functions return.

I'd suggest that you change your `array` to be an array of `node`, instead.

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[Max];
    int value;
} node;
node array[Max];
```

You don't need to initialise this array when it's declared with static storage duration (outside of functions) as you have; it starts off zeroed. You also don't need `NULL` checks like `array[index] != NULL` to check if it's been assigned to, you can just skip straight to using `strcmp` to verify the result or just check the first character to see if it's nonzero...

> ```
> array[index] = p;
> ```

You can also declare `p` to be `struct node` rather than `struct node *`, and this assignment will make sense, or you could change that to: `array[index] = *p;` for example.

As far as `malloc` goes, knowing how to use it is good, but memory allocation is a lesson I'd prefer to keep separate from data structures & algorithms, and I reckon this is an data structures & algorithms puzzle. On that note, it's best to avoid unnecessary calls to `malloc` where a more suitable storage duration may be chosen, and this kinda design is suitable for some cases (just as `malloc` and `realloc` will become later when you develop more complex hashtables) so it's perfectly okay in my mind to keep it simple.

I see another issue, which is that some of those lines of input don't have associated decimal digit values, and your error handling code for `fscanf` is incomplete and somewhat misguided. Let's cover those examples I noticed:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%s", name) == 3){}
```

I don't know what you expect to happen when `fscanf` succeeds (or fails, for that matter, or the whys and hows, as we'll cover shortly) but assuming it only writes to the one variable (`name`, in this case) it should return 1. I prefer to handle errors in indented form, so the program flows relatively unindented along the success path, so I'd write something like:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%49s", name) != 1) break;
```

I assume you can safely break from the loop here because if you can't read a word then `fp` is at end of file or in some state of error.

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &x) == 3){}
```

Now we come to the hairy parts of `fscanf`, see... We discussed one mode of failure already (the feof/error bits) but not the other: the match failures. When you try to read a decimal digit integer sequence but there is none, as explained above, the return value will be positive, but not the same as the number of fields you expect to be assigned to. In this case, expect 1, but `fscanf` returns 0, so:

```
switch (fscanf(fd, "%d", &x)) {
    case 0: // fscanf didn't assign to x, which means match failure occured...
            x = 0; // in this case I'll just zero x so we're not using stale data
    case 1: break; // ... this is where control flows when x is assigned to successfully
    default: if (!feof(fp)) {
            fputs("This is not good, because it means the stream is in state of error\n", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }
}
```

Comment: It's for an system software course, so I would rather use use malloc incase I need to translate the code for SIC. I tried what you suggested, but its still returning garbled string and int data with my output, should I edit the code part to show you what I did?

Comment: @MC_Spire, you won't use `malloc` in the kernel... When you say you tried, I edited, did you notice what else I wrote? Also, you need to show us what you tried rather than just saying you tried...

Comment: yeah sorry, I didnt refresh the page before I typed it up, I'll add my changes to the above code asap

Comment: I updated the code on the original post, I'm sorry again for being slow and not really understanding, Thank you for your help

Comment: @MC_Spire you are surely getting some kinda warning on this line: `insert(HaValue, &p);`... Do you have a question about that warning, or am I safe to assume you know how to resolve it?

Comment: That just fixed everything! Thank you! everything is now working!